# Loop my Progress Bar?

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-ui-progressbar

I have a problem.

Can someone help to fix this code so that the progressbar starts over again when it reaches 100.

I want that you can see that the work is under progress. With my code now it stops when it reaches 100.

Hope you understand my question.

Another solution could be a progressbar that jumps around on different values the whole time. The only thing thats important is that the progressbar is working all the time until you get redirected from page.

Here is the code for my progressbar at the moment.

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar();
                var value = 0;
                var timer = setInterval (function ()
                {
                  $("div#progressbar").progressbar ("value", value);
                  value++;
                  if (value > 100) clearInterval (timer);
                }, 200);
```

Answer (score 2):

what about setting to `0` again `progressBar` value when it reaches 100?

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar();
var value = 0;
var timer = setInterval (function (){
$("div#progressbar").progressbar ("value", value);
    value++;
    if (value > 100) value=0;
}, 200);
```

Comment: That was an easy solution, ty

Comment: Thanks. This not only is an easy solution but works faster than the other code I had previous.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set value to 0 when it reaches 100:

```
if(value > 100) value = 0;
```

See **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/HFArM/)**

You do not want to clear the timer as it will stop the animation.

When the page redirects, all timers will be automatically cleared/stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `window.clearInterval()`:

```
if (value > 100){
  var timer = window.clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your if statement isn't inside a block
You should have it like this

```
if(value > 100){ clearInterval(timer); }
```

Also I think the thing you want to reset here is not the interval but the value. So do it like this:

```
if(value > 100){ value=0; }
```

That should work

Comment: You don't need to have a block for if statements if your code is a one-liner.